# Flutter - how to change TextField border color?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, uitextfield, flutter-layout

I've tried everything to try and change the border color of textfield but it seems to be ignored.

I've tried sideBorder(even width is ignored too), hintStyle, applying a specific theme to only this widget and they all seem to be ignored.

```
child: new Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.white,
      accentColor: Colors.white,
      hintColor: Colors.white //This is Ignored,
      inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
               border: OutlineInputBorder(
               borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white) //This is Ignored
                    ),
                  ),
              ),
      child: new TextField(
             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, decorationColor: Colors.white),
             cursorColor: Colors.white,
             decoration: InputDecoration(
             border: new OutlineInputBorder(
             //borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
             borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.0) //This is Ignored,
                      ),
                      hintText: "Search people",
                    ),
                  ),
                  //new Divider(color: Colors.white, height: 20),

          )
```

I'd like to change that hairline looking black border and alter its color and its width.

[Image of what it currently is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8yC8.png)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `enabledBorder` and `focusedBorder` (when the textfield is focused)

```
InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.red, width: 5.0),
                  ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.blue, width: 3.0),
                  ),
              hintText: "Search people",
            ),
```

Comment: Thanks, you've been a great help!!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers, but if you only use the lower bound, then use this code:

```
    TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
          ),
        )
```